# Maintaining page breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, line-breaks

In my Rails app, I have a lot of data that is declared as `text` in the migration file. But when I print these attributes/fields out in the view, all the line breaks are lost and I get one large chunk of text. How do I maintain the line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an HTML problem. Its rules state that consecutive whitespace is converted to a single space.

Rails has a [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001719) function that wraps blocks of text in

tags so you get the separation you want